# Pasar foco de un Select a un Input Vue js | Elemet UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo un select ,con un evento que **se dispara cada vez que cambia la selección**, `ChangueSelectProduct`, y este debe **pasarle el foco a un input**, y asu vez ese **input tiene otro evento que se dispara con un enter**

**Problema:**

-Al seleccionar una opción del select con un enter, pasa al input y tbn se ejecuta el evento que tiene el input.

**Lo que espero:**

-Seleccionar una opción del select , que solo pase al input , sin ejecutar su evento

https://codepen.io/solopro10/pen/OJVONyR ---> **Selecciono una opción del select con ENTER y tambien se dispara el evento del input** (funciona normal cuando no se selecciona con enter)

Ref: 
https://element.eleme.io/#/es/component/select
https://element.eleme.io/#/es/component/input

Podrían guiarme , como puedo solucionarlo?
Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento `keyup` se gatilla cuando el usuario suelta una tecla. Un flujo de ejemplo sería:

1. Presiono una tecla
2. se gatilla `keydown` porque la tecla tocó el fondo del teclado (figurativamente)
3. Si la tecla genera ingreso de texto, se gatilla `keypress`
4. El browser procesa la acción
5. Si corresponde, dada la acción, se actualiza el estado (ej el estado del DOM) acorde a ésta.
6. Terminan los cambios de estado
7. Se gatilla `keyup` porque la tecla volvió a su posición original

Por otro lado, un select cerrado escucha a la tecla `enter`, pero un select desplegado no. Ocurre que aunque las opciones sí pueden gatillar eventos de teclado, tales eventos:

- sólo se emiten al elemento seleccionado (la opción)
- las opciones no son un elemento "focusable" (como el select o el input), luego no emiten `keydown,keypress,keyup`.

De manera que ese control se hace indirectamente desde el select con el evento change.

En tu flujo, si pinchas el select cerrado y aprietas `enter`, no se gatilla `change` y el select sí detecta las teclas (es focusable). Cuando , en cambio,  usas el enter en una opción:

1. Presiono Enter
2. Se gatilla keydown sobre el elemento que tiene el focus (la opción, no gatilla handlers)
3. La tecla no genera ingreso de texto, se omite `keypress`
4. Se procesa la acción
5. La acción gatilla un cambio de estado

   5.1. Los cambios de estado gatillan un evento change

   5.2. El evento change gatilla tu función `ChangueSelectProduct`

   5.3. Esa función cambia el foco a input de texto
6. Se procesaron los cambios de estado
7. Se gatilla keyup **sobre el elemento que tiene el focus** (**ahora es el input**). Gatilla handler.

La anomalía que ves se debe a que cambias el focus en el paso 5.3, cuando se emite `keyup` el focus cambió a un elemento focusable.

Solución: 
Utiliza `@keydown`  en vez de `@keyup` 
https://codepen.io/amenadiel/pen/ExjbgjX